# New install of helm shows traefik and traefik-crd, but why?

Tags: helm, k3s, traefik

When I run `helm ls -A` on a new install of Helm, I see,

```
$ helm ls -A
NAME        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                       APP VERSION
traefik     kube-system 2           2023-08-12 20:08:51.802846904 +0000 UTC deployed    traefik-21.2.1+up21.2.0     v2.9.10    
traefik-crd kube-system 2           2023-08-12 20:08:51.764773882 +0000 UTC deployed    traefik-crd-21.2.1+up21.2.0 v2.9.10
```

Why is it that Traefik is installed? Is this a dependency of helm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## k3s

This is actually a [default of k3s which installs traefik](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/blob/master/manifests/traefik.yaml) by default and flags the install as Helm-managed.