# Can the K3s installed Traefik be updated independently through helm?

Tags: k3s, traefik

If [k3s installs traefik and flags it as a helm chart](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/18192/18965), can it be updated through helm? When I run the commands below,

```
helm repo add traefik https://traefik.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm upgrade traefik traefik/traefik -n kube-system
```

I get the following

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: resource mapping not found for name: "traefik-dashboard" namespace: "kube-system" from "": no matches for kind "IngressRoute" in version "traefik.io/v1alpha1"
> ensure CRDs are installed first

Comment: Note that K3s uses Helm Controller for deploying the built in Helm charts. 
You can tweak existing installed charts using the `HelmChartConfig` CRD.
https://docs.k3s.io/helm#customizing-packaged-components-with-helmchartconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Install new CRDs and RBAC for Kube v1.16+

Yes, but because of the CRDs in Helm are managed by Rancher and not Traefik, and they [were changed upstream](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd/#definitions),

> The `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1` CustomResourceDefinition is deprecated in Kubernetes v1.16+ and will be removed in v1.22+. For Kubernetes v1.16+, please use the Traefik `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1` CRDs instead.

You must install the [new CRDs and RBAC's](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-crd/).

```
# Install Traefik Resource Definitions:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/traefik/traefik/v2.10/docs/content/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd-definition-v1.yml

# Install RBAC for Traefik:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/traefik/traefik/v2.10/docs/content/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd-rbac.yml
```

### Upgrade Traefik

Then you can install the Traefik repos and upgrade Traefik,

```
helm repo add traefik https://traefik.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm upgrade traefik traefik/traefik -n kube-system
```

Now you should see that the upgrade was complete,

```
❯ helm history traefik -n kube-system
REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART                   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION     
1           Sun Aug 13 18:45:21 2023    superseded  traefik-21.2.1+up21.2.0 v2.9.10     Install complete
2           Sun Aug 13 13:48:07 2023    deployed    traefik-24.0.0          v2.10.4     Upgrade complete
```

---

### Remove deprecated CRDs

Now you can optionally remove the `traefik-crd` that Rancher provides, but because the crd's are versioned, you can just keep it too.

```
helm delete -n kube-system traefik-crd
```